# Why does this Marshaling work in Mono but fail on MS?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I've boiled this down to a simple example.  I am writing some interop code between C# and C, and I have the following very simple struct on the unmanaged side:

```
typedef struct {
    bool create_if_missing;
    fdb_custom_cmp_variable custom_cmp;
} fdb_kvs_config;

typedef int (*fdb_custom_cmp_variable)(void *a, size_t len_a,
                                   void *b, size_t len_b);
```

So I've created this on the managed side:

```
public struct fdb_kvs_config
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool create_if_missing;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public IntPtr custom_cmp;
}
```

I want to use this unmanaged function

```
extern __declspec(dllexport)
fdb_kvs_config fdb_get_default_kvs_config(void);
```

And so I have this equivalent:

```
[DllImport("forestdb", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern fdb_kvs_config fdb_get_default_kvs_config();
```

However, this throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in ForestDB.Test.exe
>
> Additional information: Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.

Note:  I've tried various `MarshalAs` combinations with no luck.  Also note that I am only charged with the C# side of things, the C API is developed by someone else and I have no control over it.

If this simple signature is not P/Invoke compatible then what the heck is?  For bonus points, why does it work on OS X in Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what do you know.  Turns out `MarshalAs` was actually the problem, making the attribute almost useless on Windows.  All of the members of the struct on the managed side need to be [blittable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx).  This restriction apparently does not exist on Mono.

Comment: I don't know your requirements and restrictions, but having tried both, I prefer to write a manged C++ wrapper instead of using pinvoke.